# How to use boost::disjoint_set for image segmentation

Tags: c++, boost, graph-theory

I've read a number of questions here about people struggling with [`boost::disjoint_sets`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/disjoint_sets/disjoint_sets.html), but I'm still at a loss to understand how to use them.

There is a [reference implementation here](http://cs.brown.edu/people/pfelzens/segment/) of image segmentation by an author of the authoritative paper, and he implements in the file `disjoint-set.h` this class:

```
typedef struct {
  int rank;
  int p;
  int size;
} uni_elt;

class universe {
public:
  universe(int elements);
  ~universe();
  int find(int x);  
  void join(int x, int y);
  int size(int x) const { return elts[x].size; }
  int num_sets() const { return num; }

private:
  uni_elt *elts;
  int num;
};

universe::universe(int elements) {
  elts = new uni_elt[elements];
  num = elements;
  for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    elts[i].rank = 0;
    elts[i].size = 1;
    elts[i].p = i;
  }
}

universe::~universe() {
  delete [] elts;
}

int universe::find(int x) {
  int y = x;
  while (y != elts[y].p)
    y = elts[y].p;
  elts[x].p = y;
  return y;
}

void universe::join(int x, int y) {
  if (elts[x].rank > elts[y].rank) {
    elts[y].p = x;
    elts[x].size += elts[y].size;
  } else {
    elts[x].p = y;
    elts[y].size += elts[x].size;
    if (elts[x].rank == elts[y].rank)
      elts[y].rank++;
  }
  num--;
}
```

How would one go about replacing the above class as used in `segment-graph.h` with the Boost class?

Comment: why you want to use boost when you have a working code snip?

Comment: The above code is GPL 2, so I would like a Boost version and a more modern C++-friendly implementation. (I actually have inherited an O(N)-ish `join()` implementation that is a performance bottleneck)

Comment: isn't the link in [boost disjoint_sets](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/disjoint_sets/disjoint_sets.html) contains exactly example of connected components?

Comment: Indeed it is! When I initially tried out the class, I used `link()` instead of `union_set()` so concluded it wasn't working. When I went back, I noticed my error and discovered that as you say `boost::disjoint_sets_with_storage` is just a drop-in replacement.

Comment: I like the question. It touches on a [very rarely used, but potentially useful sublibrary of boost](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/graph-disjoint-sets-td4703790.html). Would you care to promote your last comment to a self-answer (perhaps with a slightly more elaborate explanation?).